# Java web server compare if-modified-since with last modified

Tags: java, web, server, last-modified, if-modified-since

I am trying to make a Java web server that will compare the if-modified-since with the file's last modified. 
However, I don't know how to get the if-modified-since header from the client and do the comparison.

Comment: Tell us more about your web server. Are you using an existing framework / platform / library? Are you writing networking code by hand? Do you have any code written so far?

Comment: I am going to build a web server from scratch. I am thinking about how to get the if-modified-since header from the client. No existing framework I am using. I am new to java. I don't know much about those library/ platform/ framework. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't jump right into trying to handle a particular header. If you're writing a web server from scratch then you should write a generic HTTP parser that can handle every part of an HTTP request:

- Request line

  - Request method (`GET`, `POST`, etc.)
  - URL
  - HTTP version
- Zero or more headers of the form `Name: Value`
- A blank line
- Message body

You could, for instance, build up a class like:

```
class HttpRequest {
    String method;
    URL url;
    String httpVersion;
    Map<String, String> headers;
    byte[] body;
}
```

Since header names are case insensitive I'd suggest using map with `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`.

Once you can parse *all* headers than looking for a *particular* header will be a simple task. If you had the class above it'd be as easy as looking up `headers.get("If-Modified-Since")`.